# Proof of time-invariance of a discrete-time system

Tags: discrete-signals

I have two systems that are not time-invariant.
From inserting a shifted signal, I can tell that it is not time-invariant, but I couldn't prove rigorously why it isn't time-invariant. I got confused about shifting y[n-n0] and wasn't sure how it would affect the k variable. Can someone provide proof of how it should be done?

$$y[n] = \sum_{k=-2}^2 x[k]$$

$$ y_2[n] = \sum_{k=0}^{|x_2[n]|} (n-k)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The test for LTI systems is quite simple:

> That is, if $y[n]$ is the output of a discrete-time, time-invariant system when $x[n]$ is the input, then $y[n- n_0]$ is the output when $x[n- n_0]$ is applied. (Alan V. Oppenheim, Alan S. Willsky, and S. Hamid Nawab. 1996. Signals & systems (2nd ed.). p. 51, Prentice-Hall.

This is the simple test that you would use to test for time-invariance. Now consider the first system:

$$y[n] = \sum_{k=-2}^2 x[k] = x[-2] + x[-1] + x[0] + x[1] + x[2]$$

If I shift the output to get $y'[n]$:

$$y'[n] = y[n-n_0]$$

but the input still stays the same and is **NOT** shifted by $n_0$. This is mainly due to the fact that the input is not indexed on $n$ so a shift in the output (based on $n$) does not affect the input. You can use a similar test for the second system.